# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Query Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**EDIT**

Here's the working syntax...

```
Model.where('name like ?', "%#{q}%").where('value > ?', c)
```

or

```
Model.where("name like (?)","%#{q}%").where("value > ?",c)
```

Thanks to posters for their help with this.

---

**Original Question**

I'm having trouble understanding active record syntax.

Here's what i'm trying to do

```
q = "John"
c = 50

Model.where('name like ? AND value > ?', "%#{q}%", "%#{c}%")
```

This is the wrong syntax.

What i'm trying to achieve is

```
name like John AND value greater than 50
```

How do i chain different types of queries together in ActiveRecord?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try Model.where("name like (?)","%#{q}%").where("value > ?",c).

Answer (score 4):

Don't quote q and c:

```
Model.where('name like ? AND value > ?', q, c)
```

Rails automatically converts the variables to an appropriate string for you.

Chaining refers to chaining of the where(), select(), order() functions, eg, this is equivalent to above:

```
Model.where('name like ?', q).where('value > ?', c)
```

If you want to include the % wildcard for the like bit only, you can do:

```
Model.where('name like ?', "%#{q}%").where('value > ?', c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Model.where("name like (?)","%#{q}%").where("value > ?",c)`. Or used  **scope** to help further to easy to chain

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3 using AREL,

```
ut = User.arel_table
users = User.where(ut[:name].matches("%#{q}%").and(ut[:value].gt(c)))
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."name" LIKE '%John%' AND "users"."value" > 50)
```